# Getting the method that creates runnable from thread which runs the runnable

Tags: java, methods

Suppose I have a custom `Thread` class which is responsible for running runnables

```
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    public MyThread(Runnable r) {
        super(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run(); // Can I put something here to get info about where the runnable is submitted from?
    }
}
```

Then in some method, I submit the runnable

```
public void someMethod() {
    new MyThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Blah");
        }
    });
}
```

Suppose I have no control over `someMethod`, can I modify `MyThread` such that whenever a runnable is submitted to `MyThread`, I can get info about `someMethod` (e.g. method name `someMethod`, class name) ?

**Edit**

In fact the original question is part of my problem.

I am providing a `ThreadFactory` that can be used by a threadpool (ExecutorService).

```
public class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new MyThread(r);
    }
}
```

User can create a threadpool with `MyThreadFactory`

`ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new MyThreadFactory());`

By calling pool.execute(runnable), a instance of MyThread will be created to perform the task specified by runnable. It is possible that the thread will be reused by multiple runnables. So I would like to retrieve `Method` and `Class` info in the `public void run()` method of `MyThread`. Since `runnable` is stored in a private field in the base `Thread` class, I cannot use a modified version of the solution provided by **Laerte** like:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    super.run(); 
    // Not working, Since MyThread cannot access private field target of Thread class
    Method m = target.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
    System.out.println(m.toString());
}
```

Can I still obtain `Method` and `Class` about where the runnable is instantiated , at the moment `public void run()` is invoked?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to receive?

Comment: Do you have the full code for this?

Comment: Just another thing. Did you try `Method m = this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();`?

Comment: Both in the `newThread` of `ThreadFactory` and constructor of `MyThread`, `Method m = this.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();` works perfectly :)

Comment: Very nice to hear :)

Comment: So, can you please accept my answer? I'll edit it later with this last detail. Thanks!

Comment: @Laerte I appreciate very much for your help. I know I have changed my question, but I think it is more preferable to accept solution to my true problem. What do you think?

Comment: No problem with that! I thought your problem was solved after my las comment. That's why I asked this. But, It's good to hear that I helped.

Answer (score 1):

To know things related to calling methods, class names, and so on, you should use **reflection**.

In your case, you should modify your code like this.

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    public MyThread(Runnable r) {
        super(r);
        Method m = r.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();
        System.out.println(m.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run(); 
    }
}
```

The Method class will have the method reference. Using this call `Method m = r.getClass().getEnclosingMethod();`, you will receive the method that is enclosing the Runnable object. In your case, oneMethod.

That's the idea. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: One difficulty for me is that I have no access to `someMethod`, so I cannot put code inside that method. I am hoping to get method name and class from `MyThread`. I wonder if that's possible?

Comment: I understand... So, you can use the same principle to access such Method only from MyThread. I edited the code, take a look if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: hmm.. sorry for the not providing the full picture of my situation. In fact I am providing a ThreadFactory that can be used by a threadpool (ExecutorService). By calling `threadpool.execute(runnable)`, a instance of `MyThread` will be created to perform the task specified by runnable. It is possible that the thread will be reused by multiple runnables. So I would like to retrieve `Method` and `Class` info in the `public void run()` method of `MyThread`. I will update my question with code sample. And yes, your solution addresses my original question

Comment: Hmm, I understand... I'll try to figure out a way to do it. The technique to be used should be like this one. I'll take a look again later, when I get home. It is a very interesting problem! Regards